# See executed code in Visual studio 2015

Tags: c, visual-studio, code-coverage

Is it possible with Visual Studio 2015 (and up) to have a visual feedback on which lines of code has been executed or not.

Exemple: I press F5 to debug my application. Visual hit one of my breakpoint, at this moment I want to be able to have a visual feedback of lines executed (or not) before hitting the break point. For instance green line means executed code and grey means not executed.

Totally like the code coverage of Keil. See below the green means code has been executed by the chip and grey means it has not.

[image]

[NCover](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a7CWZ68BpYo) plugins seems to do it but is there a native or a free solution?

**Why?** : Because then I do not have to step all the time until the point I'm interested in, I can just break there and see if the PC has been in all the right conditions and so on 
*(I'm not talking about test coverage, only live debug feature)*

Comment: Once your program has hit the breakpoint, do Debug-Windows->Disassembly.

Comment: There is no visualization of executed code in this window (Disasembly) unfortunately. My point is not to see disassembly (the screenshot is the only one I found where you see what I mean: green is executed code and grey not executed code yet). My point is to have a visual feedback on lines which had been executed by my program before hitting the breakpoint

Comment: OK, you should rephrase your question as it stands here I didn't understand that. Your comment OTOH is more or less clear.

Comment: Have you considered encoding your *conditions* as *assertions*, so that the compiler injects code to verify them at runtime and *you don't need breakpoints at all*?

Comment: yes I have but problem is we are talking about thousands and thousands lines of code so it would be quite long! But maybe the code coverage keil like does not exist (I think on VS2008 there was a plugin roughly working similarly)

Comment: Have you checked [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537628.aspx)?

Comment: Indeed I did, problem is all those article are about test coverage. My point is I have a program in C and I want to see what are the line executed during my usage of the program. From now I still haven"t find anything.

To picture it, in keil for instance if you put a breakpoint after your startup code, after starting the debugger when the breakpoint is hit you can see all lines which has been executed. Very helpful for complex debugging instead of stepping through thousands of lines.